# Exchange 2013 MAPI over HTTP Load balancing HAProxy

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, exchange-2013

We have successfully managed to deploy HAProxy as a Layer-4 load balancer for all our Exchange 2013 SP1 HTTP based traffic (Autodiscover, OWA, EXP, EWS, MAPI, etc.)

For various reasons, however, we are looking to move to a Layer-7 "SSL Offloading" architecture.

We have based most of our configuration on the excellent ALOHA guide : https://www.haproxy.com/static/media/uploads/eng/resources/aloha_load_balancer_appnotes_0065_exchange_2013_deployment_guide_en.pdf

The good news is that almost everything is working absolutely fine.  Our only problem is with MAPI i.e. the replacement for RPC that was introduced in Exchange 2013 SP1.

From what I have read SSL offloading of MAPI is supported by Exchange 2013 - see http://blogs.technet.com/b/rmilne/archive/2014/02/25/exchange-2013-sp1-released.aspx.  The ALOHA document advises against using Layer-7 SSL Offloading for MAPI but purely due to performance issues and not any technical reason.

If we try and load balance MAPI then the symptoms we are seeing are

- the /mapi/HealthCheck.htm URL can be returned fine in a web browser
- However, Outlook clients repeatedly ask for credentials

The relevant bits of HAProxy config are below (Its not the whole file)

```
frontend ft_exchange_2013_https
 bind 1.1.1.3:443 ssl crt /blah/blah.pem
 capture request header Host len 32
 capture request header User-Agent len 64
 capture response header Content-Length len 10
 maxconn 10000
 acl ssl_connection ssl_fc
 acl host_mail hdr(Host) -i mail.company.com
 acl path_slash path /
 acl path_mapi path_beg -i /mapi
 http-request deny if path_check
 http-request redirect scheme https code 302 unless ssl_connection
 http-request redirect location /owa/ code 302 if path_slash host_mail
 use_backend bk_exchange_2013_https_mapi if path_mapi

backend bk_exchange_2013_https_mapi
 option httpchk GET /mapi/HealthCheck.htm
 http-check expect string 200\ OK
 timeout server 600s
 server SERVER1 1.1.1.1:443 maxconn 2000 weight 10 check ssl verify none
 server SERVER2 1.1.1.2:443 maxconn 2000 weight 10 check ssl verify none
```

The things we have tried to resolve the issue are

- Use HTTP rather than HTTPS on the backend by removing the "Require SSL" flag on the MAPI IIS Virtual directory and using port 80 rather than 443 onm the SERVER1 and SERVER2 lines
- Remove one of the backend servers so all requests go to a single server
- Change the authentication settings for the MAPI Virtual directory from the default "Negotiate" to "NTLM"

However, none of these have fixed the problem.  If anyone has any ideas on how to diagnose further or has a working configuraiton they could share e.g. HAProxy config + Exchange MAPI Virtual directory config that would be great !!

Edit 1

I've also managed to reproduce the Outlook behaviour by going to https://mail.company.com/mapi/emsmdb which repeatedly prompts for credentials the same as Outlook

Comment: OK, I've found a fix to this which was to remove the option http-server-close from the configuration.